# Problem with my for loop, finding the shortest path length of a subpath using networkx

Tags: python, for-loop, networkx

So I was trying to create a code to find the shortest path length of a subpath using Networkx, basically what my code does is that it takes a 3D array to create graphs and then save them in a list so I can I use this list to find `the shortest path` and `the shortest path length` using networkx.

After that, based on the information in the lists, I want to find the shortest path length of a subpath inside the graph, if the `len` of a path is less equal than 3, then the shortest path is between the same source node and target node (so the length will be zero) and if the `len` is greater than that, then it's supposed to find the `shortest path length` between the second node in the path and the penultimate node (something like the "center" of the path), my code is below

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np


arr= np.array([[[  0., 191.,  16.,  17.,  15.,  18.,  18.],
                [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
                [  0., 141.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  18.,   0.],
                [  0., 138.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  19.],
                [  0.,  80.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  15.],
                [  0., 130.,  11.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  19.],
                [  0., 135.,   0.,  12.,  16.,  12.,   0.]],

               [[  0., 156.,  17.,  13.,  19.,  10.,  11.],
                [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
                [  0.,  21.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   6.,   0.],
                [  0., 147.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   4.],
                [  0., 143.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   6.],
                [  0.,  69.,   4.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   7.],
                [  0.,  87.,   0.,   1.,   5.,   9.,   0.]],

               [[  0., 161.,  18.,  16.,  13.,  13.,  17.],
                [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
                [  0., 138.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  21.,   0.],
                [  0.,  64.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  29.],
                [  0.,  23.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  29.],
                [  0.,   2.,  24.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  27.],
                [  0.,  61.,   0.,  24.,  29.,  26.,   0.]],

               [[  0., 163.,  12.,  13.,  17.,  19.,  13.],
                [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
                [  0., 142.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  35.,   0.],
                [  0., 122.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  31.],
                [  0.,  72.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  36.],
                [  0.,  50.,  39.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  31.],
                [  0.,   4.,   0.,  38.,  39.,  35.,   0.]],

               [[  0., 180.,  17.,  19.,  13.,  18.,  15.],
                [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
                [  0.,  44.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  46.,   0.],
                [  0.,  27.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  47.],
                [  0.,  81.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  45.],
                [  0., 116.,  48.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  45.],
                [  0.,  16.,   0.,  42.,  49.,  49.,   0.]]])

graphs= [] 
paths = []
pathlenght = []
aux = []

for i in arr :
   graphs.append(nx.from_numpy_array(i, create_using = nx.DiGraph))  #List of graphs created by the 3D array

for j in graphs:
    paths.append(nx.shortest_path(j, 0, 1, weight = 'weight')) #Shortest paths of every graph
    pathlenght.append(nx.shortest_path_length(j, 0, 1, weight = 'weight')) #Shortest path length of every graphs

for i in graphs:
    for j in paths:
        if len(j) <= 3:
            aux.append(nx.shortest_path_length(i, j[0], j[0], weight = 'weight'))
        else:
            aux.append(nx.shortest_path_length(i, j[1], j[-2], weight = 'weight'))

print(paths)         # [[0, 4, 1], [0, 5, 2, 1], [0, 5, 1], [0, 6, 1], [0, 6, 1]]
print(pathlenght)    # [95.0, 35.0, 15.0, 17.0, 31.0]
print(aux)           #[ 0. 11.  0.  0.  0.  0.  4.  0.  0.  0.  0. 24.  0.  0.  0.  0. 39.  0. 0.  0.  0. 48.  0.  0.  0.]  shape = (25,)
```

The paths and the path length is fine, but in the aux list I was expecting the output to be

```
#aux = [0, 4.0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I know the problem is with the double `for-loop` since there is 5 graphs and 5 paths, the aux list  have 25 elements, but I want to use the path according with his graph (path 1 with graph 1, path 2 with graph 2 and so on and so on) so the output of `aux` will be the same as above. 
I'm kinda new using the `for-loop`  So I was hoping you can help me, or if there is another way of doing what I'm trying to achieve, any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the corresponding pairs (graph, path) by using the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) function.

Example:

```
for g, path in zip(graphs, paths):
    if len(path) <= 3:
        aux.append(nx.shortest_path_length(g, path[0], path[0], weight = 'weight'))
    else:
         aux.append(nx.shortest_path_length(g, path[1], path[-2], weight = 'weight'))
```

Comment: It works! Geez I need to look for more of this function, thank you so much!